# Inserting and extracting numeric_limits<T>::infinity in a stream

Tags: c++, stringstream, istringstream, numeric-limits

The following program apparently shows an inconsistency when writing and reading on a `std::stringstream` a `double` set to "infinity", using `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity`.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::stringstream stream;
    double d;

    // Part 1
    d=4;
    stream << d << " ";
    d=std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    stream << d << " ";
    d=5;
    stream << d;
    stream.seekg(std::ios_base::beg);

    std::string s = stream.str();
    std::cout << "string : " << s << std::endl;

    // Part 2
    std::cout << "Extraction of data 1:" << std::endl;
    stream.seekp(std::ios_base::beg);
    stream >> d;
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    stream >> d;
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    stream >> d;
    std::cout << d << std::endl;

    // Part 3
    std::cout << "Extraction of data 2:" << std::endl;
    std::istringstream stream2(s);
    std::istream_iterator<double> iter(stream2);
    std::istream_iterator<double> eos;
    while (iter != eos)
    {
        std::cout << (*iter) << std::endl;
        iter++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

See it [live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6266d4940854f1cf).

The output is

```
string : 4 inf 5
Extraction of data 1:
4
0
0
Extraction of data 2:
4
```

In part 1 a `double` "infinity" is written to a `stringstream` and the `string` extracted from it shows an "inf" corresponding to such an infinity.

In part 2, however, the substring "inf" is apparently extracted to 0. Moreover, the stream appears to be in a bad state, since successive extractions give again 0.

Similarly, in part 3 a `istream_iterator` is used to extract the `double`s from the string. The iterator reaches an end-of-stream before reading "inf".

Obviously, one could easily fix the problem by extracting words instead of `double` and converting each of them to a "normal" double, or to `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity` when a "inf" is encountered. However, this seems like reinventing the wheel, given that the standard library already contains a lot of code to extract data from a stream....

- Why is there a difference when inserting and extracting a `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity`?
- Within the standard library, is there a possibility of extracting a `double` which could also be infinity, without resorting to write a function that extracts words and convert them to double?

**Additional note**

According to the c++ reference, [std::stod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) and similar functions already convert "inf" to an infinite expression. Hence, it looks like `std::stringstream::operator<<` does not use `std::stod` or similar to convert a piece of string to a `double`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get : _Because stage 2 filters out characters such as 'p', 'N' or 'i', the hexadecimal floating-point numbers such as "0x1.23p-10" and the strings "NaN" or "inf" may be rejected by do_get(double) even if they are valid input to strtod: this is [LWG#2381](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2381)_